# Accessing JS console data via Cypress

Tags: javascript, console, cypress

When using Cypress, I want to retrieve an arbitrary value from the JS environment, exactly as if I was pulling it from the JS console. 
In this particular case I want the value of "os.foo.env" so that I am 100% positive of an aspect of the environment I'm looking at during a test run, e.g. returning something like "server01.test.company.com ssl:true".  
 
How can I get Cypress to access that JS data?

I've not stumbled across the right thing yet because I keep finding Cypress.env references in documentation.  That doesn't seem to be what I want to do, since Cypress differentiates that specifically from accessing other environment variables, without mentioning how that might be done.

If this is simply a JS RTFM situation, I’d be more than thrilled just to get pointed to a book reference / sample.

Answer (score 0):

Using `cy.task()` to capture console output: You can use `cy.task()` to capture console output and store it in a variable. For example, you can use the following code to capture the console output and store it in a variable called console output:
javascript

```
cy.window().then(win => {
      cy.stub(win.console, 'log', msg => cy.task('log', msg)).as('consoleLog');
    });

cy.visit('http://example.com');

cy.get('@consoleLog').then(consoleOutput => {
  console.log(consoleOutput); // Output the console data to the Cypress console
});
```